# Network programming print packet received

Tags: linux, network-programming

When I print the packet received from the client over UDP.

```
printf("%02x ", buff);
```

Most bytes are normal, but there are some "string" output, just like below

```
00 11 22 33 45 56 aa ab
98 ff fe a2 d3 25 78 c6
f2 ffffffd3 ffffffc4 11 22 33 44 55
...
```

the byte d3--->ffffffd3,  c4--->ffffffc4

I do not know why this happened.

Comment: What is the type of `buf`?

Comment: buf is c char array, its size is large enough.

Comment: and the server can parse the package normally,just the output is strange.

Comment: What is exactly your question?

Answer (score 0):

Parameters will convert to int before passing to printf, because your `buff` variable is signed, so it will be extended to 32-bits with padding higher bit 1, resulting 0xFFFFFFxx.

To so you must convert it to unsigned before passing:

```
printf("%02x ", (unsigned char)buff);
```